# How to get a specific value from a Task Property array in Filenet P8 Process designer

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine

I'm designing a process using Filenet P8 Process designer. I want to check the first value of a workflow property so I'm using the expression WF_IsStepOpen[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPO4I.png) = false as shown below, where WF_IsStepOpen is a boolean workflow field array. This works correctly. However, I cannot do the same if the array is a task property, for example, F_CaseTask.IsStepOpep[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPO4I.png) = false does not work as it is an invalid expression.

Does anyone know how to get and/or set the first, or any element of a task property array?

[image]